# Use swr with Next global context: entire page gets re-rendered

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I have the following piece of code:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    const { tronLinkAuth, tronLinkLoading, mutateTronLink } = useTronLink();
    const { authenticatedUser, authLoading, authLoggedOut, mutateAuth } = useAuthenticatedUser();

    return (
        <React.StrictMode>
            <CSSReset />
            <ColorModeScript initialColorMode={theme.config.initialColorMode} />
            <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
                <AuthenticationContext.Provider value={{
                    tronLinkAuth, tronLinkLoading, mutateTronLink,
                    authenticatedUser, authLoading, authLoggedOut, mutateAuth
                }}>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </AuthenticationContext.Provider>
            </ChakraProvider>
        </React.StrictMode>
    )
}
```

Example useAuthenticatedUser:

```
export default function useAuthenticatedUser() {
    const { data, mutate, error } = useSWR("api_user", fetcher, {
        errorRetryCount: 0
    });

    const loading = !data && !error;
    const loggedOut = error && error instanceof UnauthorizedException;

    return {
        authLoading: loading,
        authLoggedOut: loggedOut,
        authenticatedUser: data as AuthenticatedUser,
        mutateAuth: mutate
    };

}
```

The code works, but my entire webpage gets re-rendered when swr propagates its result.

For example:

```
const Login: NextPage = () => {
    console.log('login update');
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Register / Login</title>
            </Head>
            <Navbar />
            <Box h='100vh'>
                <Hero />
            </Box>
            <Box h='100vh' pt='50px'>
                Test second page
            </Box>
        </>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

When using `useContext` in the `Navbar`, it also re-renders the entire LoginPage, including the `Hero`, while this is not my purpose.

```
const Navbar: React.FC = () => {
    const authState = useContext(AuthenticationContext);
    ...
```

I'm also confused as for why the logs appear in the server console, as this is supposed to be executed client-side.
*Edit*: not an issue, this is only on first render.

How to solve?

I'm interested in using swr for this use case, because it allows me to re-verify the authentication status e.g. on focus but use the cached data meanwhile.

**Edit**:
Confusing. The following log:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    console.log('app');
    const { tronLinkAuth, tronLinkLoading, mutateTronLink } = useTronLink();
    const { authenticatedUser, authLoading, authLoggedOut, mutateAuth } = useAuthenticatedUser();
```

Also gets printed out every time I switch tabs and activate the swr.
So it re-renders the entire tree? Doesn't seem desirable...

Answer (score 0):

I currently went with the easier solution, i.e. use `useSwr` immediately on the component that uses the data.

From the docs:

> Each  component has a useSWR hook inside. Since they have the
> same SWR key and are rendered at the almost same time, only 1 network
> request will be made.
>
> You can reuse your data hooks (like useUser in the example above)
> everywhere, without worrying about performance or duplicated requests.

So it can be leveraged to re-use it wherever needed without having to worry about global state re-renders.
In case there is an alternative response how to use the global Context Provider, don't hesitate to share.

Comment: this is exactly the same approach I used in one of my apps, I have a useSwr hook in each of my components knowing that due to the key, in your case api_user, the useSwr hook will always first check the cache to see if user is available, if yes, then it'll return that user and will always then make a network call to get user via the fetcher. The only other improvement I could think of is adding a revalidateOnFocus to true. This way if your user walks away for a few minutes then returns then when the window again gets focus a network request will be made to get the user.